# How to configure two front-end Apps to run parallel on Azure App service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want run two Front-end Apps in parallel on an App Service in Azure like this
[image]

I set Path mappings for App2 but its not working. Please, help!

Comment: I don't think you can expose both applications only with one Web App. Maybe you can use other services, for example, AKS.

Comment: @CharlesXu Thanks for your input, but I'll do that just by defining different routes i.e., one app on root 'site\wwwroot' and other on a sub-directory e.g., 'site\wwwroot\app2'

Comment: Could you show the `path mappings---Virtual applications and directories` in the Azure app service configuration? Refer to this https://dotnetthoughts.net/deploying-multiple-application-in-webapp/

Comment: I would help if you could explain the reasons you want to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to configure [path mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-path-mappings) in the app service configuration. You could specify each virtual directory and its corresponding physical path relative to the website root `D:\home`. You can find the physical path from your [KUDU console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benjaminperkins/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites)

> Each app has the default root path (/) mapped to `D:\home\site\wwwroot`,
>   where your code is deployed by default. If your app root is in a
>   different folder, or if your repository has more than one application,
>   you can edit or add virtual applications and directories here. Click
>   New virtual application or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use app service deployment slots.
They allow you to have multiple versions of your application running at the same time.
Also, you can swap the staging and production slots any time

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I'm trying to do something like running multiple Apps(front-end) on the same site/slot